# Static view for center row in a UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview, uipickerviewdelegate

I have a pickerView to which I add a custom view to each row by viewForRow delegate method. The goal here is to have a different view for the center(selected) row like a highlight view WHILE the pickerView spins (a center static view). Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 7, you can do this adding a subview to your `UIPickerView`. In earlier versions, it will be such a painful operation because `UIPickerView` will have a border etc, so probably you will need a custom picker-like implementation.

For iOS 7, you can use something like below:

```
CGFloat rowHeight = 100;  // rowHeight of your picker view, i assumed your rowHeight equals to 100

// Create a custom view, centered vertically in your picker view
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                         (pickerView.bounds.size.height - rowHeight)/2,
                                                         pickerView.bounds.size.width,
                                                         rowHeight)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// Do some highlighting operations
[view.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[view.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
[view.layer setBorderWidth:5.0];

[pickerView addSubview:view];
```

Comment: Oh I get the thinking behind it.Do you think there is a way of adjusting the customView of the row in view before is set selected? Because for a row to be selected it has to stop the scrolling animation. for example changing the font or color or text size inside the customView.. I mean while Scrolling

Comment: You can try subclassing `UIPickerView` and overriding `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` method. After calling `super`, maybe you will be able to customize your view.